What Does the Rambam Mean by ותלמודו (Laws of Shema 1:2)?
The Rambam in Laws of Shema states (1:2):

וּמַה הוּא קוֹרֵא, שְׁלֹשָׁה פָּרָשִׁיּוֹת. אֵלּוּ הֵן (דברים ו ד) ״שְׁמַע״ (דברים יא יג) ״וְהָיָה אִם שָׁמֹעַ״ (במדבר טו לז) ״וַיֹּאמֶר״. וּמַקְדִּימִין לִקְרוֹת פָּרָשַׁת שְׁמַע מִפְּנֵי שֶׁיֵּשׁ בָּהּ יִחוּד הַשֵּׁם וְאַהֲבָתוֹ וְתַלְמוּדוֹ שֶׁהוּא הָעִקָּר הַגָּדוֹל שֶׁהַכּל תָּלוּי בּוֹ.

An authoritative translation:

And what is it that one recites? These three sections:
"Hear O Israel..." (Deuteronomy 6:4-9),
"And if you will listen..." (Deuteronomy 11:13-21),and
"And God said..." (Numbers 15:37-41).
We begin with the section of "Hear O Israel" since it contains [the concept of] the unity of God, [the commandment of] loving Him and the study of Torah, it being a fundamental principle upon which everything is based.

But the Hebrew word is ותלמודו. And so 'the study of Torah' isn't quite right. Does this term actually mean 'studying (about) Him'? I've heard that the Sefer Habatim translates it as studying God's oneness etc. What is the best translation for the term?

ותלמודו can mean "and His Torah", "and studying Him" (or it i.e. Torah), "and His study" etc. Depends on context. They have picked the second one, and I've given my explanation as to why I think they did that in my answer.

I came across the following translation:" The paragraph Hear is recited first because it contains commandments concerning God's unity, the love of God, and the study of God, which is the basic principle on which all depends" https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Reading_the_Shema.1.2?lang=bi

I don't understand how sheets work on sefaria so I don't know who wrote that. Seems ok? Your translation skills are very good, I've noticed, so you don't need me to tell you! To understand this point in great detail, I strongly recommend this short chapter: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4094441/jewish/Mitzvas-Haamanas-Elokus-Section-1.htm

"Studying Him"
This is Chabad's translation (Rabbi Touger). It is a teaching of Chabad (and others, but not necessarily universal) that the purpose of studying Torah is to study Hashem. He reveals Himself; makes Himself known through the Torah (based on Shabbat 105a). Note also that the Rambam in Mishneh Torah, Torah Study 1:1 derives the halacha of Talmud Torah from Devarim 11:19, which is mentioned in your quote.
This is related to studying His Oneness. In Derech Mitzvotecha Heemanut Elokut Chapter 1 (also translated by Rabbi Touger!), the Tzemach Tzedek demonstrates that the mitzva of knowing and believing in Hashem is fulfilled through studying His Oneness (after bringing all the major opinions, and unifying them). The line of Shema is mentioned there.
